# Open input date popup on year select (in html)

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to open the popup from an `<input type="date" />` on the year select once you click on the calendar logo?
Normally you go to the day sect first and then have to click the year select in the popup manually, but for selecting your date of birth it would be nicer to start with selecting the year first.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way for it Since it has been created by chrome. Instead, you can search for a library or a plugin for a better way. You can use certain libraries like https://flatlogic.com/blog/best-javascript-datepicker-libraries/ or specifically  https://www.daterangepicker.com/